# Which sorting algorithm is used by Microsoft's STL::list::sort()?

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, sorting, stl

*Note: I accidentally posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717773/which-sorting-algorithm-is-used-by-stls-listsort) without specifying which STL implementation I was using, and I felt it can't really be updated since it would render most of its answers obsolete.*

So, the correct question goes - which sorting algorithm is used in the below code, assuming I'm using the STL library of Microsoft Visual C++?:

```
list<int> mylist;

// ..insert a million values

mylist.sort();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just so you don't have to rely on second hand information, the the sort code is right in the `list` header - it's about 35 lines.

Appears to be a modified iterative (non-recursive) merge sort with up to 25 bins (I don't know if there's a particular name for this variant of merge sort).

Answer (score 3):

At least in recent versions (e.g. VC++ 9.0/VS 2008) MS VC++ uses a merge-sort.

Comment: @Stephan Eggermont: That's about `std::sort()`, not `std::list::sort()`. `std::sort()` is allowed to be unstable, but `std::list::sort()` but `std::list::sort()` is not.

Answer (score 3):

STL that came with MS VC6 was the P. J. Plauger's version of the library (Dinkumware) and it used merge-sort in `std::list<>::sort()`. I dont know about later versions of MS's package.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge it is Introsoft: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

Comment: `list.sort()` cannot be implemented using an introsort -- introsort is unstable, while `list.sort()` is required to be stable.

Comment: @Stephan Eggermont: Says section 23.2.2.4/31 of the C++ standard. The documentation you're looking at is for std::sort, not std::list::sort.