# which sorting algorithm is used for std::list's sort member function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which sorting algorithm is used by STL’s list::sort()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717773/which-sorting-algorithm-is-used-by-stls-listsort)

Which sorting algorithm can be used for sorting std::list ?

Comment: duplicate of [Which sorting algorithm is used by STL's list::sort()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717773/which-sorting-algorithm-is-used-by-stls-listsort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implementation defined. However, it must follow these restrictions (§23.2.​2.4):

> Stable: the relative order of the equivalent elements is preserved.
>   Complexity: Approximately NlogN comparisons, where N == size().

So it's a stable sort with `O(nlog n)`.

Comment: Thanks GMan. Which algorithm except merge sort can be used?

Comment: @Davit: I think Quicksort can be written to be stable, though if I remember correctly it loses some performance that way. (And even though its worse-case is `O(N^2)`, its average case fits the requirements.) You're correct though, I think every implementation I have used uses mergesort. (And for non-stable sorts, Introsort.)

Comment: Looking at Wikipedia's [stable sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts), I was a bit shocked to discover that Quicksort and Shellsort aren't among them. That really doesn't leave a lot.

Comment: If my memory serves me right Merge sort is usually used for stable sorts & Intro sort otherwise (to ease up on Quick sort's `O(n^2)` worst case)...