# sorting one list without sorted function

Tags: python

```
             a=[12,11,13,21,1,2,3,45,65]
             i=0
             j=1
             k=0
             newarr=[]
             while(len(a)>=k):
                  if (a[i]>a[j]):        
                      a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]    
                      i=i+1
                      j=j+1      

             k=k+1
```

print (a)

I am not getting the intended output.
Can somebody identify?

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing algorithm in a wrong way. Well i think you should learn different sorting algorithms to sort and list in python or array in other languages.

Ex: Bubble Sort ...The easiest one to learn.

```
listing=[12,34,5,33,89,3]
for i in range(0,len(listing)-1):
    for j in range(0,len(listing)-i-1):
        if listing[j]>listing[j+1]:
            temp=listing[j] 
            listing[j]=listing[j+1]
            listing[j+1]=temp
print(listing)
```

And one more thing to mention. That the function list.sort() also uses stable algorithm to sort. 
Read here   [Which sorting algorithm is used by STL's list::sort()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717773/which-sorting-algorithm-is-used-by-stls-listsort)